# App intermittently freezing in transition (2 top level UIWindows)

Tags: ios, multithreading, uiviewcontroller, ios-animations

My app freezes intermittently in transition. Upon managing to get it frozen while in debug mode, we paused it and took screenshots. Some notes:

- in frozen state, the CPU was still reacting to taps, so it is still responding in some way
- looking at the threads, it appeared that there is no infinte loop, heavy function, or whatsoever.

However, looking at the UI ViewHierarchy surfaced an intersting thing - there were 2 top level UIWindows, with the top one being completely empty, and the button one overlayed by transition views.

What is the likely culprit here? My code included below the screenshots:

> Threads do not appear to be doing nothing 
>   [image]
>
> First of the 2 UIWindow (blank)
>   [image]
>
> Second of the 2 UIWindow
>   [image]

```
  // view controller
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let question = dataAccessor.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    delegate?.feedViewControllerDidSelect(self, question: question)
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
  }

  // delegate for viewcontroller
  func feedViewControllerDidSelect(viewController: FeedViewController, question: Question) {
    let questionDetailViewController = QuestionDetailViewController.create(question, delegate: self)
    navigationController.pushViewController(questionDetailViewController, animated: true)
  }


  // Question Detail View
  static func create(question: Question, delegate: QuestionDetailViewControllerDelegate?) -> QuestionDetailViewController {
    let vc = StoryboardScene.QuestionDetail.instantiateQuestionDetailVC()
    vc.question = question
    vc.delegate = delegate
    return vc
  }
```

Comment: any of your views have a zero height that you don't expect ?

Comment: that is likely, given we do a lot of initializations programatically, but doubt it, since the freezing is intermittent?